# Convert string to enum with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0, ecmascript-2017

How can I convert a string to Enum using generics in TypeScript?

```
export function getMethodEnum<T>(actionStr: string): T
{
    return actionStr as T; // does not work
}

export enum ActionEnum {
    Unknown = 0,
    Sleep = 1,
    Run
}

let action: ActionEnum = getMethodEnum<ActionEnum>()
```

Comment: Who is `methodStr` inside `getMethodEnum`?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir fixed sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the actual enum object to the function, since you want to map the string name of the enum to the value. This relation is stores in the enum object itself.

```
function getMethodEnum<T>(enumObject: T, actionStr: string): T[keyof T]
{
    return enumObject[actionStr as keyof T];
}

enum ActionEnum {
    Unknown = 0,
    Sleep = 1,
    Run
}

let action: ActionEnum = getMethodEnum(ActionEnum, "Sleep");
```

Comment: Can be improved a bit by restricting `actionStr` to be `keyof T`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20getMethodEnum%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(enumDefinition%3A%20T%2C%20actionStr%3A%20K)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20enumDefinition%5BactionStr%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20ActionEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Unknown%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Sleep%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Run%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20action%20%3D%20getMethodEnum(ActionEnum%2C%20'Run')%3B)

Comment: @AlekseyL. You are right, it's good you point it out, I thought about including that option, but OP seems to want to convert a random `string` to a enum.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. For random string conversion there's no point in such restriction

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you are a life saver! Not used for this but your code inspired me for another purpose

Comment: @GôTô Happy to help :)